# Uncaught TypeError when try to use IIFE

Tags: javascript, iife

I'm new at JavaScript and I'm trying to understand to logic of the functions. Here's what I try to do:

```
var GetterSetter = (function () {
    var balance = 0.0;


    var getBalance = function () {
        return balance;
    };
    var setBalance = function (amount) {
        if (amount > 0) {
           return balance = amount;
        }
      };
})();

GetterSetter.setBalance(120);
```

When I try to run that. I got :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setBalance' of undefined
>       at GetterSetterScript.js:16

Comment: Your function returns **nothing**. That's why you get error

Comment: You need to return an object with the functions as methods.

Comment: You could actually define true getters and setters rather than using methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `GetterSetter` does not exist as a method of `setBalance`.

You need to set the function in your code. I have provided and example for you:

**code**

```
var GetterSetter = (function () {
  var balance = 0.0;
  return {
    getBalance: function () {
      return balance;
    },
    setBalance: function (amount) {
      if (amount > 0) {
        return balance = amount;
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 4):

use

```
return {
    getBalance:getBalance,
    setBalance:setBalance
}
```

at the end of the function

Comment: Or in ES6, simply `return { getBalance, setBalance }`